# How to verify checksum in a .mds file format?

Tags: checksum

I got the hadoop checksum file from https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.1/hadoop-2.7.1.tar.gz.mds. But the file format is not the ones expected by tools like `sha256sum`. What tools should I use to read checksum in a `.mds` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take a look inside the file with a text editor. It's a plain text file containing lots of different hash formats, so you are free to choose which one to use for verifying your file checksums.

In general, when faced with such a situation, I'd suggest you run the unix `file` utility against the file. It will give you detailed information about the contents of "strange" files.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt mention what OS you are using but still you can use MD5SUM

In Linux make sure your data file and MD5SUM files are at same location

then do `md5sum -c mdsfile` and it will check md5sum automatically.

for more information please look at

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Comment: I tried `md5sum` and `sha256sum` at first, but they do not read the `.mds` format.

Answer (score 0):

Read the original article [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html).

Here is the complete procedure to verify the releases, by using GPG or by using SHA-256.

**GPG**:

1. Download the release(hadoop-X.Y.Z-src.tar.gz) from a [mirror](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common) site.
2. Download the signature file hadoop-X.Y.Z-src.tar.gz.asc from [Apache](https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/hadoop/common/).
3. Download [Hadoop KEYS](https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/hadoop/common/KEYS) file.
4. Run these command separately:

> gpg --import KEYS

```
gpg --verify hadoop-X.Y.Z-src.tar.gz.asc
```

**SHA-256**:

1. Download the release(hadoop-X.Y.Z-src.tar.gz) from a mirror site.
2. Download the checksum hadoop-X.Y.Z-src.tar.gz.mds from [Apache](https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/hadoop/common/).
3. Run

> shasum -a 256 hadoop-X.Y.Z-src.tar.gz

Comment: I know how to use those tools. The problem is that the format in the `.mds` file is unknown.

Comment: Okay, I have downloaded your .mds file and then right clicked on it and opened it in Notepad++. Here's the image:
 http://i.stack.imgur.com/4aVKz.jpg

Answer (score 0):

That file is messed up. Anyway you can extract it as follows:

```
mv hadoop-2.7.1.tar.gz{.mds,}
gunzip hadoop-2.7.1.tar.gz
mv hadoop-2.7.1{.tar,.txt}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cat hadoop-3.1.1.tar.gz.mds | grep "^SHA256" | sed 's/ //g' | sed 's/SHA256=//'` will then give you something you can check with sha256sum.